# How can I access a modified QLabel?

Tags: qt

I am instantiating an editable QLabel like so:

```
QLabel foo("some text");
foo.setTextInteractionFlags(Qt::TextEditorInteraction);
```

I can click the text and modify it, and the modified text must be in a buffer somewhere, but even after examining the data fields in Qt Creator I don't see where it is:

```
QString notmodified = foo.text(); // only returns the original text
```

is the modified text somewhere that I can access it?

EDIT: I think using something else is indeed an easier way, but I'm still interested in knowing the answer to my question.

EDIT: OK, it's been a week. "Answered".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say that even though you can set this flag on a `QLabel` (the `Qt::TextInteractionFlag` is used by other widgets than `QLabel`), it is not designed to be edited.

Why don't you use a `QLineEdit` ?

Comment: Absolutely - this is making life complicated for yourself, and probably the user, since the UI experience will not be sensible, especially in terms of accessibility. If you want editable text, use a QLineEdit. What you might want, is to hide the QLabel and replace it with a QLineEdit when clicked, then restore the QLabel when the QLineEdit loses focus.

Comment: What if you still wanted to grab it? There must be some way to still access this data? I'm still curious for the sake of actually answering the OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

For editable text field you have a good choise, QLineEdit or QTextEdit. Use one of these widgets. QLabel is just for labeling.